# Scala How do I create a empty variable

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a empty variable to later add anything to that variable,
I tried using the method in here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/initialize-scala-variables-option-none-some-null-idiom/ but get an syntax error "Cannot upcast None to Option"  I want to do something like this:

```
var empty = //blank
empty = //any type
```

Comment: A `var` cannot change its type. If it starts out as `Any` then it remains `Any`, i.e. useless.

Comment: Is there any other way to do something like this?

Comment: Yeah there is another way, do not do that, rethink your approach, and do something else.

Comment: Another way? It's called Python. But seriously, what you're trying to do goes against the very premise and principles that Scala was built on. If you don't have the time and bandwidth to learn new approaches to problem solving, that's OK, sometimes you just have to get things done. Scala will be here when you're ready.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice.

Comment: Perhaps if you could edit your question to add a bit of context around it, you could receive some interesting answer about possible alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:
But it is not Scala standard.

```
var x:Any = None

x = Option("hi")

x = "Hello"

println(x) // Hello
```

Comment: Try`x.isEmpty` or anything else that can be done with a `String` (or `Option[String]`).

Comment: We all know using `Any` is not good idea. But if you want this way with `Any`, you can use type cast which is extra work--- like:  `x.asInstanceOf[String].isEmpty`

Comment: The OP obviously doesn't know using `Any` is not a good idea. It's information worth including in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get `Cannot upcast None to Option` is because of the type inference.

When you wrote `var something = None` you probably had in mind something like "Ok it's a `None` right now but I will give it some Int value later", e.g `Some(2)` or `Option(2)`.
But the inferred type for `var something` was `None`, because the type inference cannot guess better, and you cannot change the type of a `var` as @jwvh commented.

However you could also write `var something: Option[Int] = None`, hence locking the type that suits you, and give it the value `Some(2)` later.

(obviously I used `Int` as the desired type but you can replace with the type that suits you)